# For Each loop and stop when certain name is found

Tags: sorting, for-loop

So basically I am creating a simple application that gets all files in a folder. These files are listed inside a listbox and then when the user presses a button it will sort all the files into new folders based on a "breaking point" if you will. Ex: File 1.3ds, 2.3ds, 3.3ds and 4.error.3ds are listed in the listbox. I want the button to sort files 1.3ds, 2.3ds and 3.3ds into a folder and delete 4.error.3ds. Then the next folder would be 5.3ds, 6.3ds, 7.3ds and delete 8.error.3ds. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Folder Hierarchy would look like This
New Folder: Contains 1.3ds, 2.3ds and 3.ds
New Folder (1): Contains 5.3ds, 6.3ds and 7.3ds

I have a total of 54,000+ Files and doing this manually is not an option but it needs to be done.

Comment: If you're looking for help, you need to share your code.

Comment: I don't have any code that's what I need help with. The only code I have is on 1 button that retrieves the files. My second button is to do what the post is about but I have no idea how to go about doing it. I'm fairly new to coding.